# LUMA no longer displaying menu/categories after upgrading to 2.2.3

Tags: magento2.2.2

I've just successfully upgraded from 2.2.2 to 2.2.3, and after which Luma no longer displays the menu / sub-categories or the logo on the main page of my website (www.seafordart.com.au), however when you click on a product it does display it correctly ..

Does anybody have any clue?

Comment: have you: redeployed static content? reindexed? cleared cache several times?

Comment: I have indeed done these already

Comment: check in the answer

Comment: I dont understand your last comment? (check in the answer)

Comment: I meant, check MY below answer :) i didnt' see your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure to run below commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have however tried all these previously (and again now) the problem still remains

Comment: have you given rights to var, generated and pub???

Comment: rights given to var/ - generated/ - pub/ drwxr-sr-x 10 www-data www-data

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

before this you can check the status of categories index running

```
php bin/magento indexer:status
```

If this is not the matter, have you checked that all the categories are anchored?
Also, is the tree correct and all the subcategories assigned to the default category? Maybe some branch of the category tree is broken

Comment: Done this, same problem and I have checked that the Default Category and all other Categories are anchored

Comment: have you tried with a different theme? like with the blank magento theme?